# .Net Core Dependency Injection IdbConnection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, idbconnection

I have a .NET MVC app that uses autofac for Dependency Injection.
When the app starts the following code registers IDbConnection

```
var connectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
this.Register(c => new SqlConnection(connectionString)).As<IDbConnection>().InstancePerRequest();
```

I am trying to find how to do the same in .Net Core MVC using the default dependency injection mechenism that the framework offers.
I am thinking of adding something like this

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IDbConnection, SqlConnection>();
```

but I don't know where to add the connection string

Answer (score 21):

I Believe I found it.
It is

```
services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>(db => new SqlConnection(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnectionString")));
```

Comment: Yes using the factory delegate overload is the correct approach in this scenario.

Comment: `AddScoped` would be the equivalent of `InstancePerRequest`. `AddTransient` is the equivalent of `InstancePerDependency`.

Comment: Are you sure for that? I thought it was the opposite. I thought  AddScoped is the equivalent for InstancePerDependency

Comment: I'm getting mixed results with this and I think it might have something to do with how connection pooling is done. Basically, I have 3 repositories that all have IDbConnection injected as transient. If I query each repository in parallel, I get a MARS error which tells me they're all using the same connection.

Comment: If you make IDbConnection transient, will this conflict with singleton Business Services? I'd rather not make my stateless Business Services transient since that will consume unnecessary memory.