# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' while attempting to activate 'Register.Controllers.RegsController'.

I almost certainly know that I have to add something to my Startup services, I just have no idea how or what to add. Everything online is related but not quite the same.

**Confugtation (Startup.cs)**

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>                  
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext")));       
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class RegsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
    protected readonly SqlConnection _dbc;


    public RegsController(SqlConnection dbc, ApplicationDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _dbc = dbc;
        _context = context;
        webHostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
    }
....................
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(RegViewModel model)
    {
....................
            string supName = DataHelper.ExecuteScalar<string>(_dbc, @"SELECT Supplier 
            FROM [DBName].[dbo].Sellers
            WHERE Supplier = @regSupplier");
            if (supplierName == "Joes Fishing")
            {
                _context.Add(Reg);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }

            //...
```

`DataHelper` is just a class with my SQL queries and execute scalar, won't post for now since it is private but it is unrelated and the issue persists just calling the `SqlConnection dbc` in the controllers constructor.

Any point in the right direction on even what or how to search for what I am looking for, relevant projects that use similar `ExecuteScalars` I have worked on have no obvious connection services or *Startup.cs* etc

Comment: When the framework instantiates your controller, it doesn't know how to get an instance of `SqlConnection`. This you need to register in your start up.

Comment: This might get you started https://stackoverflow.com/q/51194626/2030565

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to use your `DataHelper` in your controller.

But I think it's not the best practise. You can register the `sqlhelper` in your project. And you can use it in your controller.

---

Blow repo is a good sample, it will be useful to you.

[Core.MSSQL.SqlHelper](https://github.com/learnwithkawsar/.netcore.mssql.sqlhelper)

Comment: Cheers, that looks good thanks!

Comment: I can't get that example working, run into other issues

Comment: @mcr.netcore You can post another post to ask for help. This way should be the best practice.